# Skipping iteration if condition not met

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements

Currently messing around with a fantasy football program, The user is asked to first input 10 player names which are added to a list, then input values for each individual player for different variables like goals scored, goal assists etc. The first question is "did they play the match?"

If the answer is no then I am trying to skip the following questions and jump to the next player, I have been trying to use continue but it just loops and continues asking the first question to the first player.

```
    playerList=[]

def Playeradd():
    playerList.append(item)


def Playercreate():
    global item
    item = raw_input("Enter Player name: ")

    Playeradd()



[Playercreate()for _ in range (5)]

print
print "You have selected", len(playerList), "players for your squad, Your selected squad is.."
#print playerList
for item in playerList:
    print item


player =Playercreate
scorecheck=[]
x=0
totalscore=0

def pointsaward():
    global scorecheck, totalscore
    y=1
    player=y
    x=0
    while x < 5:
        print
        print "Please enter score for ", playerList[x]

        print

        play = raw_input(" Did he play the match (yes or no?) ")
        if play == "yes":
                play1=2
        else:
                 play1=0


        goalS= int(raw_input(" Did he score, if so how many?"))
        goalS=goalS*5

        goalA= int(raw_input(" How many assists?"))
        goalA=goalA*3

        motm= raw_input(" Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) ")
        if motm == "yes":
            motm1=5
        else:
            motm1=0

        yelC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) ")
        if yelC == "yes":
            yelC1= -1
        else:
            yelC1=0

        redC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) ")
        if redC == "yes":
            redC1= -5
        else:
            redC1=0                              


        PenM=raw_input(" Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) ")
        if PenM == "yes":
            PenM1= -3
        else:
            PenM1=0



        playerpoint1= play1+goalS+goalA+yelC1+redC1+PenM1

        PlayerandScore= [playerList[x],playerpoint1,]
        scorecheck.append(PlayerandScore)
        totalscore+= playerpoint1

   # print "This player has scored a total of ", PlayerandScore, " this week "
        x+= 1
        y+= 1
        print "This player has scored a total of ", PlayerandScore, " this week "
        print

pointsaward()
```

Sorry if it was unclear,So for Player 1 If the answer to the first question is no then there is no need to ask the following questions about the player as he would not have played. So I want it to skip the following questions and start asking the input for Player 2 in the list.

Comment: Maybe you want to *`break`* out of the loop?

Comment: Post the full code please. It is difficult to understand "but it just loops and continues asking the first question to the first player". What should the code do?

Comment: I would move all your IF statements under the first IF. That way if yes then do all the other IFs. If no then loop back to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put the question inside a function. This will allow you to call the function when ever you want.
and make it easier to decide when to ask the question.

Because you have raw_input I am assuming you are using python 2.X

you can add python2 or python3 to your tags to get better help from people know more about each version of python.

```
list_of_players = ["player 1","player 2","player 3"]

def check_player(yes_no):
    if yes_no == "yes":
        play1=2
        goalS= int(raw_input(" Did he score, if so how many?"))
        goalS=goalS*5
        goalA= int(raw_input(" How many assists?"))
        goalA=goalA*3
        motm= raw_input(" Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) ")
        if motm == "yes":
            motm1=5
        else:
            motm1=0
        yelC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) ")
        if yelC == "yes":
            yelC1= -1
        else:
            yelC1=0
        redC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) ")
        if redC == "yes":
            redC1= -5
        else:
            redC1=0                              
        PenM=raw_input(" Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) ")
        if PenM == "yes":
            PenM1= -3
        else:
            PenM1=0    
    else:
        play1=0
        return "no"
        print "player did not play"
# this for statement will ask about each player in the list of players.  
for player in list_of_players: 
    print "Did "+player+" play in the game?"
    print check_player(raw_input("yes or no --->"))
```

here is an image of the console if you run my code.

[image]

EDIT: Ok here is your code fixed up to check each new player after you enter their info or say "no".

```
playerList=[]
def Playeradd():
    playerList.append(item)
def Playercreate():
    global item
    item = raw_input("Enter Player name: ")

    Playeradd()

[Playercreate()for _ in range (5)]
print "You have selected", len(playerList), "players for your squad, Your selected squad is.."

for item in playerList:
    print item

player =Playercreate
scorecheck=[]
x=0
totalscore=0
def pointsaward():
    global scorecheck, totalscore
    y=1
    player=y
    x=0
    while x < 5:
        print "Please enter score for ", playerList[x]
        for player in playerList: 
            print "Did "+player+" play in the game?"
            play = raw_input(" Did he play the match (yes or no?) ")
            if play == "yes":
                play1=2
                goalS= int(raw_input(" Did he score, if so how many?"))
                goalS=goalS*5
                goalA= int(raw_input(" How many assists?"))
                goalA=goalA*3
                motm= raw_input(" Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) ")
                if motm == "yes":
                    motm1=5
                else:
                    motm1=0
                yelC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) ")
                if yelC == "yes":
                    yelC1= -1
                else:
                    yelC1=0
                redC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) ")
                if redC == "yes":
                    redC1= -5
                else:
                    redC1=0                              
                PenM=raw_input(" Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) ")
                if PenM == "yes":
                    PenM1= -3
                else:
                    PenM1=0
            else:
                play1=0
                print player+" did not play"
        playerpoint1= play1+goalS+goalA+yelC1+redC1+PenM1
        PlayerandScore= [playerList[x],playerpoint1,]
        scorecheck.append(PlayerandScore)
        totalscore+= playerpoint1
        x+= 1
        y+= 1
        print "This player has scored a total of ", PlayerandScore, " this week "
pointsaward()
```

Comment: sorry I had to clean up the code a bit. I updated it in the question. Try the new code.

Comment: NOTE: You should add your list. This would help me throw something together for you. I did not realize you were imputing a list to this question.

Comment: I added my code assuming you wanted to pass in a list. If that is what you want to do then the code in my answer will now ask you to say yes or no for each player

Comment: @Grimble6 let me know if this updated code helps. It seams to work for me.

Comment: I keep getting errors, My list is made through user input I updated the original question with the full code if it helps

Comment: @Grimble6 I took your code and fixed it up. I condensed it a little so it would look nice on stack overflow. Also make sure to use indent properly. The code did not copy paste well so I am just making sure you have everything indented well.

Comment: @Grumble I am curious to know if this worked for you? I have tested it on my end.

Comment: When I run the code it just prints the score from the first player not all five of them, It then asks user to enter scores again but prints the next players score (player2),

Comment: @Grimbel6 I only attempted to answer the question you originally asked. If what I have given you does solve the problem of asking the questions for the next player after you type "no" then you should accept this answer. If you are stuck on another problem in  your code then you should ask a separate question so people can help. Let me know when you post your next question and I will take a look at it as well :)

Comment: Sorry about that, Your solution for the original problem works perfect thanks again for that, I posted a new question with my next issue                                http://stackoverflow.com/q/43583374/7400763

Comment: Cool I will check out your next question. Note: If you get an answer that solves the problem of your question then make sure to select the check mark next to the answer that best solves your problem. This will help other users who find this post with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your question you just need to continue as normal, naturally ending the if statement

```
play = input(" Did he play the match (yes or no?) ")
if play == "yes":
    play1=2
else:
      play1=0
print("Continue Here")
```

Comment: I need it to skip the following questions and start asking the next player I have in my list