# Loop/Nested Loop problems Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, loops, variables, while-loop, nested

I want the program to ask each of the five players the seven questions, calculate the player score and then display a list of each players score eg
Points for week 1
player1 43
player2 26
player3 38     etc etc

Then ask the players the questions again and do the same for week 2.

Currently the program will only display the first players score, then ask the questions to all five players again but only display the second players score, it repeats this five times while only iterating through the players.

Where am I going wrong, any help will be much appreciated

```
 playerList=[]
def Playeradd():
    playerList.append(item)
def Playercreate():
    global item
    item = raw_input("Enter Player name: ")

    Playeradd()

[Playercreate()for _ in range (5)]
print "You have selected", len(playerList), "players for your squad, Your selected squad is.."

for item in playerList:
    print item

player =Playercreate
scorecheck=[]
x=0
totalscore=0
def pointsaward():
    global scorecheck, totalscore
    y=1
    player=y
    x=0
    while x < 5:
        print "Please enter score for ", playerList[x]
        for player in playerList: 
            print "Did "+player+" play in the game?"
            play = raw_input(" Did he play the match (yes or no?) ")
            if play == "yes":
                play1=2
                goalS= int(raw_input(" Did he score, if so how many?"))
                goalS=goalS*5
                goalA= int(raw_input(" How many assists?"))
                goalA=goalA*3
                motm= raw_input(" Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) ")
                if motm == "yes":
                    motm1=5
                else:
                    motm1=0
                yelC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) ")
                if yelC == "yes":
                    yelC1= -1
                else:
                    yelC1=0
                redC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) ")
                if redC == "yes":
                    redC1= -5
                else:
                    redC1=0                              
                PenM=raw_input(" Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) ")
                if PenM == "yes":
                    PenM1= -3
                else:
                    PenM1=0
            else:
                play1=0
                print player+" did not play"
        playerpoint1= play1+goalS+goalA+yelC1+redC1+PenM1
        PlayerandScore= [playerList[x],playerpoint1,]
        scorecheck.append(PlayerandScore)
        totalscore+= playerpoint1
        x+= 1
        y+= 1
        print "This player has scored a total of ", PlayerandScore, " this week "
pointsaward()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think if you change how your call the information a little by using another function and you use a dictionary instead of a list in this case for getting the information of player/score you will be better able to manage changes to the code and also have an easier time manipulating the data.

Her is what I got so far.

```
playerList=[]
def Playeradd():
    playerList.append(item)
def Playercreate():
    global item
    item = raw_input("Enter Player name: ")

    Playeradd()

[Playercreate()for _ in range (5)]
print "You have selected", len(playerList), "players for your squad, Your selected squad is.."

for item in playerList:
    print item

player =Playercreate
scorecheck={} # using a dictionary rather than a list. Because you only have to values to look at this to me seams the best option for displaying data.
x=0
totalscore=0
def pointsaward():
    global x, totalscore,scorecheck
    scorecheck={}
    while x < 5:
        print "Please enter score for ", playerList[x]
        for player in playerList:
            print "Did "+player+" play in the game?"
            play = raw_raw_input(" Did he play the match (yes or no?) ")
            if play == "yes":
                play1=2
                goalS= int(raw_input(" Did he score, if so how many?"))
                goalS=goalS*5
                goalA= int(raw_input(" How many assists?"))
                goalA=goalA*3
                motm= raw_input(" Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) ")
                motm1=0
                yelC1=0
                redC1=0
                PenM1=0
                if motm == "yes":
                    motm1=5 #this was missing from the math in total points
                else:
                    motm1=0
                yelC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) ")
                if yelC == "yes":
                    yelC1= -1
                else:
                    yelC1=0
                redC=raw_input(" Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) ")
                if redC == "yes":
                    redC1= -5
                else:
                    redC1=0                              
                PenM=raw_input(" Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) ")
                if PenM == "yes":
                    PenM1= -3
                else:
                    PenM1=0
                playerpoint1= play1+goalS+goalA+yelC1+redC1+PenM1+motm1
                scorecheck[playerList[x]] = playerpoint1
                x+= 1
            else:
                play1=0
                scorecheck[playerList[x]] = (player+" did not play")
                x+= 1

def printResults(): # added a simple function run the point adding function and print the results.
    pointsaward()
    print "This player has scored a total of ", scorecheck, " this week "
printResults()
```

This should result in something returned like the following. Note: I changed the amount of players being looked at to 2 to make testing go faster. so this information below will only show the results of looking at 2 players.

```
Enter Player name: ads
Enter Player name: qwe
You have selected 2 players for your squad, Your selected squad is..
ads
qwe
Please enter score for  ads
Did ads play in the game?
 Did he play the match (yes or no?) yes
 Did he score, if so how many?5
 How many assists?5
 Did he win man of the match (yes or no?) yes
 Did he recieve a yellow card (yes or no?) no
 Did he recieve a red card (yes or no?) no
 Did he miss a peno(yes or no?) no
Did qwe play in the game?
 Did he play the match (yes or no?) no
This player has scored a total of  {'ads': 47, 'qwe': 'qwe did not play'}  this week
```

Comment: That works alot better, Im still new to pyhon so I need to learn about dictionaries. Im trying to get it to ask the questions again for week two but it keeps printing an empty list

Comment: I would need to see how you are asking the question for week two You might want to ask another question :D . And there are a good amount of things you can do with dictionaries, list, and tuples. Its just a matter of figuring out what will work best for the situation. You can even format how you print the information out so it will discard all the unwanted characters such as `{} : ' "`

Comment: Im just trying to ask the same questions again and then print the player list with the combined scores from week one and two

Comment: the best option there is to create a global variable that can store combined scores.

Comment: Also what you are asking is really a different question "Code Wise" than this question. It sounds like you want to be able to combine each weeks scores for each separate player. This is best asked in a separate question after you have made some attempt creating the code yourself. I am not able to answer a question like that here as it would confuse the people reading the original post. So the best option is to ask a new question so it can be answered properly

Comment: I have posted a new question